# Help needed: sudo passwd -l

Tags: ubuntu, passwd

I used the command `sudo passwd -l` on my own user account in Ubuntu and now I can't log in anymore. Is there any way to unlock that?

I tried adding "!" in front of my password but it still didn't work. What should I do?

Comment: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LostPassword

Comment: @mashuptwice I'm fairly sure they will need to modify that advice to use `passwd -u {user}` rather than change the password with `passwd {user}`

Comment: "I tried adding "!" in front of my password but it still didn't work" Adding more invalid characters won't help.  (https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/passwd.1.html)(the manpage) suggests `-l` _adds_ character(s) to the hashed password to invalidate all passwords; to undo that, you'd have to _remove_ passwords.  I agree with the LostPassword community method.

Comment: @roaima I'm sure that simply setting a new password should have the same effect

Comment: A quick test shows the lock remains even after a password change (`passwd -l test1; passwd test1; passwd -S test1`)

Answer (score 2):

Why would you do that?
`man 5 passwd;man 5 shadow` shows that the 2nd colon separated field of `/etc/shadow` is the encrypted password. That's where the `!` was prepended (stuck on the front). The 1st field is the username.

If you cannot `sudo passwd -u $USER`, you'll have to edit `/etc/shadow` VERY CAREFULLY and remove only the `!` at the beginning of the encrypted password for your userid.

Editing `/etc/passwd` or `/etc/shadow` can be done 3 or 4 different ways:

1. With `vipw`. Use the `$EDITOR` and `$VISUAL` environment variables to specify which editor to use - you're not locked to `vi`.
2. Shutdown to single user mode or reboot into single user mode. That single user is `root`.
3. Reboot from a Live USB, mount the disk, and edit `/etc/passwd`and `/etc/shadow` on the disk, e.g. `/mnt/mydisk/etc/passwd`.
4. `sudo vi /etc/shadow`

Answer (score 0):

If you have no other accounts that can run `sudo`, then you will have to boot another OS. Create a rescue live OS, on a USB-storage-device. Boot it, and edit the password file, to remove the `!`.

However if you can add another `!`, then you can remove both of them, and it should work again.